# Can't open mouse settings in Control panel

Tags: windows-8, mouse, touchpad

When I click on any mouse related items anywhere in the Control Panel windows nothing happens.  When I click on other links the options open.
There are no mouse related entries in the Dell program group in the start menu, and no icon in the bottom right by the clock.  There is no application-blocking firewall running, only an internet traffic firewall (Comodo).

I tried uninstalling the mouse driver (Dell Touchpad) and rebooting.
My question is:
How Can i open mouse settings in Control Panel - Windows 8 ?

Comment: Open **run** & type **main.cpl** & see if opens the mouse settings ?

Comment: That opens "Mouse Settings."  There are no touchpad options, just things like swapping buttons, double click speed, and pointer speed.  At least that opens something.

Comment: I discovered that when I reinstalled the driver it placed an icon in the group in the bottom right by the clock.  It was hidden and I had to click the arrow to see it.  That opens the Dell Touchpad settings, and it works.  All of the links to the mouse in the control panel do nothing, and searching for touchpad instead of mouse returns no results.  So the Control Panel is broken, but I can get to the setting another way.

Comment: Try run **sfc /scannow** & check if the same problem is there in a different computer account